# Dynamic table name linq-to-sql dynamic LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I want to construct my query dynamically based on the contents user has selected, and I want to do this in LINQ-t0-SQL. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543639/dynamic-table-names-in-linq-to-sql), but I don't want to use SQL statements with datacontext.

On Googling a bit I have a feeling that this can be done using dynamic LINQ. Would someone provide an example of similar scenario with dynamic LINQ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d/) is the link you need. 
**Update.** Some details: you can use the SearchType method from the post to obtain a type using the table name and then use [Dynamic LINQ](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Dynamic-LINQ.aspx) to write queries you like.